# How to find system library properties in Nios 2 IDE v12?

Tags: intel-fpga, nios

I'm trying to make a project according to the [spec](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/labos/index.html)
but the dialogs seem to have changed completely in version 12.

I don't nearly get similar dialogs in Nios 2 IDE v12.

This is what I search:

[image]

This is what I get, and nothing leads to a dialog like in the spec:

[image]

How do I find the system library properties in version 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you select `File->New->Project` ? I'm on `NIOS2IDE 12.0` and that seems to work.

[image]

Next dialog shows this, where I specify the location of the already existent BSP.

[image]

Then select `Your BSP (left column, right click)->NIOS2->BSP Editor`

[image]

Comment: Then I get a wizard where I can't select "Nios II C/C++ Application". It's not working.

Comment: It says I must make a new BSP when I select Nios II Application and after that I still can't get to the system library properties.

Comment: I could also choose Nios II Application and BSP from Template which also does not lead to a system library properties. I use Nios 2 IDE v12.0

Comment: What if you select `File->New->Nios2 Application` same result?

Comment: Been there three times with no system library properties, can try again just for Pete's sake.

Comment: Ah, what you want is probably `BSP editor`, there you can select stdin, out, err devices and such. Check my updated post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22660/discussion-between-jgr-and-nick-rosencrantz)